# How to exclude messages by masked string

Tags: grafana-loki

I need to remove the number which is changing in a string when running `!=` in a query. Example:

> Message = maintainInventoryDetail ERROR: Open task exists: 9315433 for this Reference. CAN'T BE UPDATED. Please re-enter.

My query is not working when using `*` to replace the number:

```
topk(5, count by(Receiver, QdocName, Message) (
 rate(
  {filename="$filename"}
  | logfmt
  | pattern `$pattern` 
  | Result = ` error` 
  | Message != `maintainInventoryDetail ERROR: Open task exists*for this Reference. CAN'T BE UPDATED. Please re-enter.`
 [$__interval])))
```

I'm expecting all messages without those containing number

Answer (score 1):

For [filtering based on extracted labels](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#label-filter-expression) you can use `!~` to filter using regexes, same as it is used in [stream selectors](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#log-stream-selector).

For your case, you can simply replace number that is changing with `\d+`. For more information on regexes, please refer [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

So, your final filter might look something like this:

```
| Message !~ `maintainInventoryDetail ERROR: Open task exists \d+ for this Reference. CAN'T BE UPDATED. Please re-enter.`
```

---

Please note, that the regex expression must match against the *entire* string, **including newlines**. For more details, please, refer to [Log stream selector](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#log-stream-selector) documentation.